# How to get first occurrence non zero key value pair from any associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array:

```
$pair = array(
  'S'=>'0',
  'I'=>'50',
  'P'=>'30'
);
```

From this pair of key and values, I need first occurrence non zero value from key value pair only,
from my example I'm expecting key `I` and value `50`.

Comment: Do you want only first value or whole array, what if other values are also 0, do you want to add or skip those values in array

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
function findNonZero($var){
    // returns whether the input is non zero
    return($var > 0);
}

$pair = array(
    'S'=>'0',
    'I'=>'50',
    'P'=>'30'
);

$newPair = array_filter($pair, "findNonZero");
var_dump($newPair); //Contains array of non-zero values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with usual foreach loop

```
$pair = array(
  'S'=>'0',
  'I'=>'50',
  'P'=>'30'
);


foreach($pair as $k=>$v)  {
   if ($v) break;
}
echo "$k => $v"; // I => 50
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/950373)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php functions [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), or use a foreach loop.

```
<?php
// filter out empty values, and get first item
$value = array_slice(array_filter($pair), 0, 1);

// check not empty
if (!empty($value)) {
    // get key
    echo 'key   => '.array_keys($value)[0].PHP_EOL;

    // get value
    echo 'value => '.array_values($value)[0];
}
```

https://3v4l.org/tr3bp

**Result:**

```
key   => I
value => 50
```

Or use a loop:

```
<?php
$value = [];
foreach ($pair as $k => $v) {
    if (!empty($v)) {
        $value[$k] = $v;
        break;
    }
}

if (!empty($value)) {
    echo 'key   => '.array_keys($value)[0].PHP_EOL;
    echo 'value => '.array_values($value)[0];
}
```

https://3v4l.org/tPeAq

**Result:**

```
key   => I
value => 50
```

Or use a [generator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php),

```
<?php
$getNoneEmpty = function() use ($pair) {
    foreach ($pair as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            yield [$key => $value];
        }
    }
};

// get first
$value = $getNoneEmpty()->current();

if (!empty($value)) {
    echo 'key   => '.array_keys($value)[0].PHP_EOL;
    echo 'value => '.array_values($value)[0].PHP_EOL;
}

// or loop over all
foreach ($getNoneEmpty() as $value) {
    echo 'key   => '.array_keys($value)[0].PHP_EOL;
    echo 'value => '.array_values($value)[0].PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/mnnHl

**Result:**

```
key   => I
value => 50
key   => I
value => 50
key   => P
value => 30
```

Many ways to skin a cat, though, if you don't want the key/value you can also do it differently.